# What is happening behind bash forward process substitution?

Tags: bash, process

According to the wikipedia,  "Process substitution can also be used to capture output that would normally go to a file, and redirect it to the input of a process."(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution).

So, in my own words, that means with process substitution, I can take the output of the command A and use it as the input of the command B. In other words, it's like a pipe(is this correct?).

So if this true, and if I do this:

```
echo "test" >(wc)
```

then I should expect to get the following:

```
1 1 5
```

because my understanding of the above command is similar to the following:

```
$echo "test" > tmp
$wc tmp
1 1 5 tmp
```

except I don't make the tmp file with the process substitution.

But instead I get the following output:

```
test /dev/fd/63
```

This obviously indicates somehow my mental model is incorrect. Where am I wrong?

I understand the <(command). For example

```
$diff <(head file1) <(head file2)
```

perfectly makes sense. but not >(command).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`Process Substitution`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution)

> The process list is run with **its input or output connected to** a FIFO or some file in **/dev/fd**. **The name of this file is passed as an argument to the current command** as the result of the expansion.  If the >(list) form is used, **writing to the file will provide input for list**.

What happens with `echo "test" >(wc)`?

The file `/dev/fd/63` is opened for connecting `echo test` with `wc`. `wc` is started with it's input connected to `/dev/fd/63`. Then the name of this file (`/dev/fd/63`) is passed as an argument to the current command (`echo "test"`), resulting in `echo "test" /dev/fd/63`. This is why you see

```
test /dev/fd/63
```

as output. `wc` waits for input, but since `echo` doesn't write to `/dev/fd/63`, the count will be `0`.

If you want this to work, you must create a script, which takes the last argument and echos the first `N-1` arguments into the last

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "${@:1:$(($# - 1))}" >${@: -1}
```

When you call this

```
bash script.sh test >(wc)
```

you will see the expected output

```
1 1 5
```

Comment: Or, much more simply, use: `echo test > >(wc)`, which redirects the output of 'echo` to the file specified by the process substitution.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Wow! I'm really impressed. So, the name is not passed as an argument, but literally appended to the command string. Thank you.

Comment: See the discussion in the `bash` manual on [Shell Expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) and following sections which describe the specific expansions, and then [Redirections](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections) which occurs after all the expansions.

Answer (score 2):

Your mental model is incorrect in that you've missed one important detail: Process substitution is not redirection.

When you perform a redirection such as "echo test > tmp", what's executed is "echo test", and the stdout (represented by ">") is directed into the file named "tmp". When you perform a substitution, such as "echo test >(wc)", the "wc" is executed, and the ">(wc)" is replaced by the name of a file (or possibly the name of a magical device) that can be read or written to.

As quoted from the Wikipedia page you linked to: "Under the hood, process substitution works by creating a named pipe, and then substituting its name on the command line."

If you look closely at the "diff" example above, you'll see that there as well, it works the same way. After all, what are the arguments to "diff" but file names on the command line?

Comment: so does that mean the precedence of the execution is 1) wc inside >() and 2) echo command?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, using the other example `$ tee >(wc -l >&2) < bigfile | gzip > bigfile.gz`, here bigfile is read and becomes the input to the wc -l inside the >() and that output is taken as a input to the tee?

Comment: The example `$ tee >(wc -l >&2) < bigfile | gzip > bigfile.gz` is equivalent to `$ cat bigfile | tee >(wc -l >&2) | gzip > bigfile.gz`. The tee command gets bigfile on stdin, stdout is a pipe to gzip, and tee's **command-line argument** is a filename representing the stdin to the wc process.